# How can I get access to the current selection inside a D3 callback?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

How can I get access to the current selection inside a D3 callback?

```
group.selectAll('.text')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .text((d) => d)
    .attr('class', 'tick')
    .attr('y', (d) => {
      // console.log(this) <-- this gives me window :( but I want the current selection or node: <text>
      return d
    })
```

I could do a `d3.select('.tick')` in the callback, since by then I've added a class and can get the node via d3.select, but what if I didn't add the class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is the use of an arrow function to access `this`.

It should be:

```
.attr("y", function(d){
    console.log(this);
    return d;
})
```

See here the documentation about arrow functions regarding `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

It says:

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and lexically binds the this value (does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target).

To get the current DOM element `this` in an arrow function, use the second and third arguments combined:

```
.attr("y", (d, i, n) => {
    console.log(n[i]);
    return n[i];
})
```